# Merge column data from some rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to merge the data of some columns from some rows.

For example I have :

| Name | ID | Data | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 100 | Blue | 001 |
| Name1 | 101 | Grey | 001 |
| Name1 | 102 | Grey | 001 |
| Name1 | 103 | Black | 001 |
| Name2 | 200 | Red | 002 |
| Name2 | 201 | Green | 002 |

And I would like to have :

| Name | ID | Data | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 100 | Blue | 001 |
| Name1 | 101 | Grey | 001 |
| Name1 | 102 | Grey | 001 |
| Name1 | 103 | Black | 001 |
| Name2 | 200 | Red | 002 |
| Name2 | 201 | Green | 002 |
| Name1 | 001 | Blue,Grey,Black |  |
| Name2 | 002 | Red,Green |  |

My file have 62,000 rows. I can change some headers, add/delete/modify columns and all in less than 5 seconds.
But on this part I'm getting a bit stuck. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Simlock, see [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if you had time to try answers out you can comment your problems below them, up- or downvote, and possibly accept the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+`agg` to compute the new rows, then `pandas.concat` to merge it with the original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df,
           (df.groupby('Parent')
              .agg({'Name': 'first', 'Parent': 'first', 'Data': ','.join})
              .rename(columns={'Parent': 'ID'})
              .reset_index(drop=True)
           )
          ]).fillna('') # optional fillna to remove the NaNs
```

```
    Name   ID                  Data Parent
0  Name1  100                  Blue    001
1  Name1  101                  Grey    001
2  Name1  102                  Grey    001
3  Name1  103                 Black    001
4  Name2  200                   Red    002
5  Name2  201                 Green    002
0  Name1  001  Blue,Grey,Grey,Black       
1  Name2  002             Red,Green
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding how the agg function works but I'm trying to read the documentation.
In my case, I don't want to see duplicate values.
I will try your solution

Comment: @Simlock Then instead of `','.join` use `lambda x: ','.join(set(x))`

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution helped me to achieve my goals. 
There is just one last detail I am trying to figure out, your function turns my parent into a floating number. For example 001 becomes 001.0

Comment: well, you can use the new [integer NA](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), other than that, `001` is not a valid integer in python, leading zeros are not permitted, so either use a string or accept to have `1`

Comment: Yes it's true, I didn't think of that when I created my example. In fact my CSV has numbers like 75043610 which becomes 75043610.0
In my example, 1 becomes 1.0
I will look at your function

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of unique colors per parent with `groupby.unique`, and then make them a single value with `.str.join`:

```
>>> parents = df.groupby(['Name', 'Parent'])['Data'].unique().str.join(',')
>>> parents
Name    Parent
Name1   001       Blue,Grey,Black
Name2   002             Red,Green
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

If your pandas option is to old you could replace `.unique()` with `.agg(set)`:

```
>>> parents = df.groupby(['Name', 'Parent'])['Data'].agg(set).str.join(',')
```

Then some tweaking to make it fit the initial dataframe’s format, and then we can simply append it:

```
>>> parents = parents.reset_index().rename(columns={'Parent': 'ID'}).assign(Parent='')
>>> parents
     Name   ID             Data Parent
0  Name1   001  Blue,Grey,Black       
1  Name2   002        Red,Green       
>>> df.append(parents)
     Name   ID             Data Parent
0  Name1   100             Blue    001
1  Name1   101             Grey    001
2  Name1   102             Grey    001
3  Name1   103            Black    001
4  Name2   200              Red    002
5  Name2   201            Green    002
0  Name1   001  Blue,Grey,Black       
1  Name2   002        Red,Green
```

Comment: Hello Cimbali,
I can't seem to use ".unique". It doesn't exist and even in the Pandas documentation I don't see it.

Comment: GroupBy.unique is documented here @Simlock: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html What pandas version are you using?

Comment: @Simlock I’ve updated with an alternative

Comment: Thanks Cimbali!
I have version 1.3.3. Maybe the 'unique' function wasn't working because I'm working with a dataframe and not a series.
In any case, GroupBy and Agg are the functions I needed, I didn't know how to use them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You’re welcome @Simlock. See [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)